# Updating data from DE to other DE in Exact Target?

Tags: exacttarget

I need to update data onto one data extension of other data extension of exact extension and data should save in the form of JSON.

How can I achieve this? I am new to Exact Target.

Comment: Please put forth a good faith attempt in your question. Otherwise you're unlikely to get much help.  Plus, there's a dedicated SF community over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com).  Please use the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Answer (score 0):

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165100/updating-data-from-de-to-other-de-in-exact-target

Set Primary Keys and data in Data Extensions can be updated with Query using a Select Statement.